# Opposite of "expanded"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, terminology, antonyms

I am looking for the word to use when saying the opposite of *expanded/expand/expansion*. Here is an example of how I want to use the word:

> In the summer the wood expanded, now it is winter and the wood
>   (________).

Also, if there are other antonyms for *expand*, please let me know.

Comment: Contracted/contract/contraction or shrank/shrink/shrinking ought to work.  I can hear my father explaining, "Wood expands when it is moist and then, when the air is dry, it shrinks."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Contract](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contract)

> The wood contracted.

See the second definition.

> v.intr.
>   1. To enter into or make an agreement: contract for garbage collection.
>   2. To become reduced in size by or as if by being drawn together: *The pupils of the patient's eyes contracted.*

=== edit Added antonyms and usage ===

For other opposites, try http://www.synonym.com/antonyms/expanded/.

> Antonym of contract (Sense 9) =>abridge, foreshorten, abbreviate, shorten, cut, contract, reduce"

Here, I'm using *expanded* and its antonym as a transitive verb.

> He expanded/abridged his novel.
>
> She expanded/foreshortened her perspective.
>
> He expanded/abbreviated his speech.
>
> She expanded/shortened her trip.
>
> They expanded/cut her research budget.

Here, I'm using *expanded* and its antonym as an intransitive verb

> The bridge expanded/contracted as the temperature changed.
>
> His waistline expanded/reduced with exercise.

Answer (score 12):

In computer applications design, we usually use components that have an *accordion* behavior. In that sense, we call the opposite of *expand* as ***collapse***.

You can see an example of that behavior [here](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Comment: "collapse" has a very different meaning when used with physical objects; Consider *the wood shrank* vs. *the wood collapsed* (or try replacing "wood" with "bridge").  While it's appropriate in your computing domain, it's not suitable for the question's stated need.

Comment: I thought it might answer the *"Also if there are other antonyms for expand please let me know"* part of the OP question.

Comment: Fair enough, I overlooked that bit.  :-)

Comment: Since this answer has more upvotes than the accepted answer, I think more people are looking for it in this context, including me. So I'm happy the answer didn't get removed.

Answer (score -1):

The opposite of expand is compress
I got this because expand is to let out and compress means to press together

Comment: Thanks for the answer and welcome to the site.  It is helpful to add a dictionary definition to an answer to show how it fits.  In your example, you may find that compress is an action done upon something else rather than an reaction to something that happens.